# How to sort list of domain names by subdomain followed by (top level domain name) TLD

Tags: perl

I have a file containing several lines of domain names as given below

```
yahoo.com
somesite.cc
mysite.net
voa.org
voa.co.aus
www.voa.org
google.com
```

I have to read the file and sort first by the TLD (com, co, net etc), followed by the domain name (yahoo, google, voa etc) and them subdomain name (aus, in etc). After sorting I have to save them in a file. The sorted file output should be

```
somesite.cc
voa.co.aus
voa.co.in
google.com
yahoo.com
mysite.net
voa.org
```

If someone give me a head start, that will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on your needs, you may need external resources or far more than a regex/split/sort. Why? Because if you have `example.co.uk`,  the correct split is `example` + `co.uk` and not `example.co` and `uk`. This case is even more complicated becaus nowadays you can register directly under `.uk` which was not the case previously. You have many such cases and no automated way to handle them. Have a look at the "Public Suffix List".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to build a custom [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) like the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(max);

chomp( my @data = <DATA> );

my @sorted = sort {
    my ( $aa, $bb ) = map [ reverse split /\./ ], ( $a, $b );
    (   grep {$_}
        map { ( $aa->[$_] // '' ) cmp ( $bb->[$_] // '' ) }
        ( 0 .. max( $#$aa, $#$bb ) )
    )[0] // 0
} @data;


print "$_\n" for @sorted;

__DATA__
yahoo.com
somesite.cc
mysite.net
voa.org
voa.co.aus
www.voa.org
google.com
```

Outputs:

```
voa.co.aus
somesite.cc
google.com
yahoo.com
mysite.net
voa.org
www.voa.org
```